# "Customer" or someting else?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, terminology, copywriting

Now designing an app for two sided market - for interpreters and their customers. So there would be two sections - for interpreters and for customers. I have stucked a little bit with the titles in the app bar.

[image]

[image]

I think title "Customer" doesn't suit well... it is dull and not informative. In other fields there are good and informative terms for opposite parties - doctor & patient, rider & driver, teacher & student, etc. And what could you suggest for my situation? Thanks.

BTW this is simply two sections of an app - first for Customers and second for Interpreters. Each of them have their own content.

Comment: How about "Client"? And why did you put profile category as header title? What is the content of the page? If it is a profile page, why don't you use it as a subtitle, and his/her name as a header title?

Comment: I agree with @Rosiana please use 'client' word

Comment: Lets say I am a interpreter. Is this a page with all the clients I have? Is this a page of one of my Clients? Is this my actual profile as others see it?

Comment: @Alvaro: ... Or is it simply my page as an interpreter, because as an interpreter, I am also the OP's client?

Comment: Yes, it is simply two sections of an app - first for Customers and second for Interpreters. Each of them have their own content.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use "User", "Client" or "Beneficiary". In the relationships "doctor & patient", "teacher & student" is implied a more profound element, an ethical one and here is just about a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

As the app you are developing sounds like you are providing a service, why not "Service User?"

The NHS use it a lot as patient is starting to become a pejorative term.